# After updating Android Studio Its showing an error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo

> Error: The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project
>   ':app'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in error, SDK version is not compatible, So upgrade SDK Version to 19.1.0.

Most Importantly, read error properly and if you are not getting meaning of error then search a little bit before posting question here.

See this too : [Android Studio Gradle BuildTools Revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999714/android-studio-gradle-buildtools-revision)

Answer (score 1):

Change version for you `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19  
  buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
...
}
```