# Android Studio 0.8.0 Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project XXX. Minimum required is 19.1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After a day of research I still can't figure out how to fix this problem!
I created a build.gradle file in eclipse because we decided to switch to Android Studio (0.8.0)! 
However, after the export I got the Error: Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.3) is too low for project ':XX'. Minimum required is 19.1.0!

I installed the Android-SDK Build-tools from the SDK Manager, i manually configured the build.gradle file and I tried configure it with the "Open Module Settings" but nothing helped!

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 20
   buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
   defaultConfig {}
   productFlavors {}
}
dependencies {}
```

Maybe somebody know what the problem is!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999714/android-studio-gradle-buildtools-revision) person had a similar problem, and the answers there may help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please update Android Studio to 0.8.1. Then you should replace `apply plugin: 'android'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`. Regarding the issue, you need to make sure that you have build tools 20.0.0 installed.